# Where/How to state global JS variables in Ruby on Rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, variables, global-variables

I would like to state a global JavaScript variable for my Ruby on Rails 7 project. In Rails 5 I was used to state global JS variables in *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* like this:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js (Rails 5)

var MY_GLOBAL_VAR = MY_GLOBAL_VAR || {};
```

... but in Rails 7 the directory *app/assets/javascripts/* seems to be no longer used in favour of *app/javascript/*. In Rails 7, I tried to state global variables in files such as *app/javascript/application.js* () without success. I also tried to create the file *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* and state there the global variables without success.

In the browser's Console I always get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MY_GLOBAL_VAR is not defined

Where/How can I state global JS variables in Rails 7?

Comment: you can always define a `<script>` tag in your layout's `<head>` to define any JS you need, if it's something you need globally I think it's ok to do that there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about

```
window.MY_GLOBAL_VAR = window.MY_GLOBAL_VAR || {}
```

in the `app/javascript/application.js`

Of course you need include this file in the top of `application.html.erb`