# Custom JS files in app/assets/javascripts/ break the Stimulus assets pipeline (Rails 7)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, stimulusjs

I'm trying to [add custom JavaScript in a Ruby on Rails 7 project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75760784/824806), so:

1. I created the file *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* containing my custom code.
2. In *app/assets/config/manifest.js* I added (found) the following code.

File *app/assets/config/manifest.js*:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
```

3. I restarted the server.

Now, when I visit my app pages then Stimulus doesn't work anymore even if in the browser's Console tab I don't get any error. And I have this problem even if the file created at step 1 is an empty file.

The only thing I noted in the browser's Network tab is that when the *application.js* file is present in the *app/assets/javascripts/* folder then the Stimulus controller files don't load. When I remove the *application.js* file from *app/assets/javascripts/* everything works again (after restarting the server).

Without *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

[image]

With *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

[image]

What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `application.js` from `app/javascript`. All the asset helpers will look for a matching file in asset paths and return the first match:

```rb
>> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application.js").filename
=> "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/javascript/application.js"
#                                     ^          ^

>> Rails.root.join("app/assets/javascripts/application.js").write("var GLOB;")

>> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application.js").filename
=> "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/javascripts/application.js"
#                                     ^                  ^
# now it returns a different file for the same "application.js"
```

In your layout, it does the same, just through javascript helpers:

```rb
>> helper.javascript_include_tag("application")
=> "<script src=\"/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js\"></script>"
>> require "open-uri"
>> URI.open(helper.javascript_path("application", host: "http://localhost:3000")).read
=> "var GLOB;\n"

>> Rails.root.join("app/assets/javascripts/application.js").delete
>> reload!
>> URI.open(helper.javascript_path("application", host: "http://localhost:3000")).read
=> "import \"@hotwired/turbo-rails\";\nimport \"controllers\";\n"
```

---

Name the file something else:

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/globals.js

const GLOBAL = "setting";
```

Add it to manifest:

```js
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= globals.js
// or add the whole directory
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

Load it:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "globals" %>
```

---

To do this in javascript modules, add globals to `window`:

```js
// app/javascript/globals.js

window.GLOBAL = "setting";
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

// you have to do this in a separate file, because imports will run first
window.LOADED = "after imports";

import "./globals";
import "./components"; // <= can use GLOBAL now; LOADED is not assigned yet
```

However, you should just import what you need where you need it, instead of relying on global variables.

Comment: thanks. The second approach ("do this in javascript modules") seems to work, not the other one. I'll use the working one.